# Django Rest Framework serialization fails on post requests

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a seializer class

```
class StudentJournalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = StudentJournalModel
        fields = (
            'value',
            'date',
            'discipline',
            'para_number',
            'student',
            'is_module'
        )
```

Which I cant get to work as I need it to.
I want it to display not the pk values for ForeignKey fields but actual field values plus this class should work for post methods as well.

Usually I used to add:

```
student = serializers.CharField(
    source='student.username'
)
discipline = serializers.CharField(
    source='discipline.discipline'
)
para_number = serializers.CharField(
    source='para_number.para_position'
)
```

However it only works with GET  `read_only=True`

But I need to use it during post requests from client app to create new objects in database so it obviously wont work. I read that i need to write the .create() method to handle such case but I dont really understand how it works and what i need to overwrite there, so I would really appreciate if someone can explain how it should be and why.

Attaching code for the model as well:

```
class StudentJournalModel(models.Model):

    value = models.CharField(
        max_length=55,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name="Value",
        default=''
    )
    date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name="Date"
    )
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(
        'department.Disciplines',
        verbose_name="Discipline"
    )
    para_number = models.ForeignKey(
        'department.ParaTime',
        verbose_name="Class #"
    )
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        verbose_name="Student"
    )
    is_module = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name="Module value"
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s, %s, %s" % (self.date, self.discipline, self.student.get_full_name())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [SlugRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).

Note that you need to make sure that the slug field has a unique constraint.

Comment: What would be the queryset equal to in my case?

Comment: unless you need to set some restriction, it'll be the <related model>.objects.all()

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose all the fields for the model it's enough to just say:

```
class StudentJournalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = StudentJournalModel
        depth = 1
```

From docs: The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a flat representation.

This will work to GET the nested resource also, for POST you will need to send the ids for related fields, it should be enough to create the new object. The student, discipline and para_number should already exist in database, if any of them should also be created then you need to write .create() method yourself see this nice little exemple from [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)